# I want to have tabs displayed vertically on the left hand side with Jquery Tools Tabs. Can anyone help me out?

Tags: css, jquery-tools

I'm using the minimal setup except I've edited the CSS somewhat in a previous project and I have copied and pasted into this one.  It's not much I've just changed the thickness of the border and colors.  So does anyone know how to manage getting the tabs to be displayed vertically on the left hand side of the pane?

Comment: IMHO, for minimal headaches, I'd stay far away from jQuery Tools.  By his own admission, the developer is easily distracted so it's not maintained for many months at a time.  Also, the ridiculously large amounts of required HTML/CSS markup turns the jQuery tagline, _"write less, do more"_ completely upside down.

Comment: So what would you recommend then?  I'd like a tabs setup with tabs vertical on the left side.

Comment: I don't use jQuery for tabs but there are literally hundreds of [nice jQuery plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+tabs+plugins&btnG=Search&client=safari&rls=en&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

It would need a bit of tweaking to tidy up, but you could do the basic switch by modifying the stylesheet with this CSS, or adding this to your page

```
<style>

.tabs {
    float: left;
}

.panes {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float: none;
}

</style>
```

I'm quite impressed with JQuery Tools, very neat. Good luck!